# possible to retrieve time left on a glib 'event?'

Tags: c, linux, timer, glib

I am creating an event with `g_timeout_add` or `g_timeout_add_seconds` which returns an event id; I can cancel the event by calling `g_source_remove`.

However, at some point what I would like to do is see how much time is remaining until the event is fired.  Is there a simple way to do this with the glib api, or do I need to manually store and compare timestamps with `g_source_get_current_time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reasonable way to do this in GLib.

The unreasonable way would be to get the GSource (g_main_context_find_source_by_id) and then invoke the source->source_funcs->prepare() operation on the GSource, which would return the time until the source should be dispatched. This is kind of sketchy: source_funcs is private, and prepare() isn't really intended to be used except internally by the main loop.

Best I can tell it would work though. I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks;  I'd rather not depend on any private functionality that may or may not change, so I guess I'll have to keep track of the time myself.

Answer (score 2):

save the start time + timeout interval, subract from current time when you want to know the time left.